# Как нужно указывать id с параметром?

Tags: php, html, javascript

Нужно с помощью одного кода выводить разные id:

```
 document.getElementById("'cntdwn' + elem_id").innerHTML = FinishMessage;    
 document.write("<span id="'cntdwn' + elem_id"></span>");
```

В середине не правильно.

Comment: в середине какого именно 1 код не правильно?

Comment: В обоих.
Я не знаю как правильно.

("'cntdwn' + elem_id")

<span id="'cntdwn' + elem_id">

Comment: ниже приведён правильный синтаксис. от себя могу лишь добавить, что данная конструкция на выходе Вам предоставит `span`с `id` равным `cntdwnelem_id`. На мой взляд не совсем красиво. Требуется также добавить определённые символы, например, чтобы результат был таким `cntdw_elem_id`. Получаем конструкцию `<span id=\"cntdw"+'_'+elem_id"\">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('cntdwn' + elem_id).innerHTML = FinishMessage;    
document.write('<span id="cntdwn' + elem_id + '"></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<span id=\"cntdwn" + elem_id + "\"></span>");
```